# Average squared of angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

Consider spin $S$ particles. Is there an easy way to prove that $\langle \vec{S} \rangle \cdot \langle \vec{S} \rangle \leq S^2$ for all states? I understand intuitively that the bound is realized with $|S,m=S\rangle$ state and all rotations of this state, but I don't know how to prove this inequality.

Comment: what do you mean by $\langle \vec S\rangle$?

Comment: If you use $\vert S,S\rangle$ then you get $\langle \vec S\rangle=S$ and so the bound is not reached since the eigenvalue of $S^2$ is $S(S+1)$… unless you don’t mean that $S^2$ is the usual operator.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you mean
$$\langle \vec S\rangle \cdot \langle \vec S\rangle \equiv \sum_k \langle S_k \rangle^2 \leq \langle S^2\rangle \equiv \langle\sum_k S_k^2\rangle$$
$$\iff \sum_k \left[\langle S_k^2\rangle - \langle S_k \rangle^2 \right]\geq 0$$
Since $\langle A^2 \rangle - \langle A\rangle^2 \geq 0$ for *every* self-adjoint operator $A$, it is true in particular for each $S_k$, and so the desired result follows immediately from this.  All that remains is to show that my claim about $A$ is true.

Note that $$\langle A^2\rangle - \langle A\rangle^2 = \left<\big[A-\langle A\rangle\big]^2\right>$$
so it suffices to prove that $\langle B^2\rangle \geq 0$ for all self-adjoint operators $B$ (more generally, we would have that $\langle B^\dagger B\rangle \geq 0$, so when $B^\dagger=B$ we obtain the desired result as a special case).  Using the fact that $B$ is self-adjoint and that $\langle \psi,\psi\rangle \geq 0$ for all $\psi$ in the Hilbert space, this becomes a one-line exercise.

---

It appears that I was mistaken, and that the OP means

$$\langle \vec S\rangle \cdot \langle \vec S \rangle \equiv \sum_k \langle S_k\rangle^2 \leq s^2$$
where $S^2 = s(s+1) \mathbb I$.  This inequality can be demonstrated by noting that $\vec S$ is a [vector operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_operator); as a result, $\langle \vec S \rangle$ transforms like a 3-dimensional vector under rotations, and so $\langle S \rangle \cdot \langle S \rangle$ transforms like a scalar (i.e. not at all).  Therefore, without loss of generality we may rotate any state to $|s,s\rangle$ without changing the value of $\langle \vec S \rangle \cdot \langle \vec S \rangle$.

If the system is in an eigenstate of $S_z$, then $\langle S_x\rangle = \langle S_y \rangle = 0$, which can be shown from the commutation relations. As a result, after rotating to $|s,s\rangle$ we simply have that $\langle \vec S \rangle = s \hat z$, and so it follows that we have the **equality**

$$\langle \vec S\rangle \cdot \langle \vec S \rangle = s^2$$

Comment: I thought about this approach but the inequality you derived is $\langle \vec{S} \rangle \cdot \langle \vec{S} \rangle \leq S(S+1)$. But I think the inequality is stronger, i.e.  $\langle \vec{S} \rangle \cdot \langle \vec{S} \rangle \leq S^2$.

Comment: @AlexanderNikolaenko Oh, I see. Traditionally the uppercase $S$ refers to the operator and the lowercase $s$ refers to the spin, i.e. $\langle S^2\rangle =s(s+1)$.

Comment: @AlexanderNikolaenko I have amended my answer to address your clarification